# add group by back to data frame

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe in Pandas as below which is storing name of Team won and Name of stadium where it won as below

```
d={"Winner":["Team1","Team2","Team3","Team1","Team2","Team1"],
         "Stadium":["S1","S2","S3","S1","S2","S1"]}

score=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d)
```

Now I have performed some calculation with  group by on above data frame to find count of each team and match won at a stadium as :

```
 score.groupby(by=["Stadium","Winner"]).size().reset_index()
```

Now, I want to add these count values back to my data frame.

I am facing issue with multiple group by columns.

Any help.

Comment: `score.groupby(by=["Stadium","Winner"])['Stadium'].transform('size')
`

Comment: @Wen Thanks, can you tell me the purpose of ['Stadium'] here.

Answer (score 2):

This is what `merge` is for:

```
score.merge(
    score.groupby(by=["Stadium","Winner"]).size().reset_index(),
    on=["Stadium", "Winner"]
)
```

Comment: thanks am real new to pandas and trying to deploy my 1st project.

Comment: also how to give column name to this?

Comment: No problem. Use the `rename` method (Google it).